# Sabre Webservices EnhancedAirBook with infant

Tags: php, web-services, sabre, sabredav

Hello everyone i'm trying to create a PNR, im using EnhancedAirBook + PassengerDetails at this moment i has cretated PNR for ADT and ADT + CNN without problems, but when i do the same but including an infant EnhancedAirBook returns this error ***Specified HaltOnStatus Received - Processing Aborted***

In this case im trying to Book a flight BCN MAD for 1 ADT + 1 CNN + 1 INF

EnhancedAirBookRQ

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7" version="3.7.0" HaltOnError="false">
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>
      <RetryRebook Option="true"/>
      <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
      <HaltOnStatus Code="US"/>
      <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
      <OriginDestinationInformation>

      <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-06-12T11:00:00"  ArrivalDateTime="2018-06-12T12:25:00" FlightNumber="1101" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="A" Status="NN">
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MAD" />
        <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="1101" />
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="BCN" />
      </FlightSegment>
      <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-06-16T09:30:00"  ArrivalDateTime="2018-06-16T10:45:00" FlightNumber="930" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="A" Status="NN">
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BCN" />
        <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="930" />
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="MAD" />
      </FlightSegment>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="5" WaitInterval="2000"/>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>
    <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
      <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
        <OptionalQualifiers>
          <PricingQualifiers>
            <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" /><PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1" /><PassengerType Code="INF" Force="true" Quantity="1" />
          </PricingQualifiers>
        </OptionalQualifiers>
      </PriceRequestInformation>
    </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
      <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="500"/>
    </PostProcessing>
    <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false"/>
  </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

EnhancedAirBookRS

```
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_7">
        <ApplicationResults
            xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Incomplete">
            <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-05-26T12:01:57.688-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="ERR.SP.HALT_ON_STATUS_RECEIVED">Specified HaltOnStatus Received - Processing Aborted</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Error>
        </ApplicationResults>
        <OTA_AirBookRS>
            <OriginDestinationOption>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="06-12T12:25" DepartureDateTime="06-12T11:00" FlightNumber="1101" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="A" Status="QF" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MAD"/>
                    <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="1101"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BCN"/>
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="06-16T10:45" DepartureDateTime="06-16T09:30" FlightNumber="0930" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="A" Status="QF" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BCN"/>
                    <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="0930"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="MAD"/>
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationOption>
        </OTA_AirBookRS>
        <TravelItineraryReadRS>
            <RetryRebook Successful="false"/>
            <TravelItinerary>
                <CustomerInfo/>
                <ItineraryInfo>
                    <ReservationItems>
                        <Item RPH="1">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0301" ArrivalDateTime="06-12T12:25" DayOfWeekInd="2" DepartureDateTime="2018-06-12T11:00" ElapsedTime="01.25" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="1101" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="O" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" IsPast="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MAD" Terminal="TERMINAL 4" TerminalCode="4"/>
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="32A"/>
                                <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="1101"/>
                                <Meal Code="G"/>
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BCN" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCIB"/>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>06-12T12:25</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>06-12T11:00</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                        <Item RPH="2">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0301" ArrivalDateTime="06-16T10:45" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2018-06-16T09:30" ElapsedTime="01.15" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0930" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="O" SegmentNumber="0002" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" IsPast="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BCN" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1"/>
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="32A"/>
                                <MarketingAirline Code="IB" FlightNumber="0930"/>
                                <Meal Code="G"/>
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="MAD" Terminal="TERMINAL 4" TerminalCode="4"/>
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCIB"/>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>06-16T10:45</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>06-16T09:30</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                    </ReservationItems>
                </ItineraryInfo>
                <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                    <Source PseudoCityCode="K3FJ"/>
                </ItineraryRef>
            </TravelItinerary>
        </TravelItineraryReadRS>
    </EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

I hope you can help, thanks for your time.

Comment: Your segment status is UC. Doesn't appear to be related to infant, rather to the availability of the segments you are trying to book.

Comment: A few comments on your request. Generally you should book your test pnr flights at least 3 month in advance and if you want to guarantee that they get booked use: ResBookDesigCode="Y"

Answer (score 0):

In your request I can see HaltOnStatus Code="UC", and you are in fact having that status in your response (Status="UC") for both segments.

In this case it seems the airline rejected both flights, maybe because of the lack of space or for any other reason. In such a case, you should discard this itinerary. However, there is an element that can help by booking the segments in QF status (that's a special status that does not take inventory from the carrier, and does not check actual availability) and then doing WPNCB, which will book real segments for the given options in the cheapest class of service. You can activate that with RetryRebook Option="true"just before HaltOnStatus.